# Memoizing a method on an object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

In JS I'd do:

```
var o = {
  foo: memoize(foo)
};
```

How do I do memoize an instance method in TypeScript similarly?

```
class C {
  // How do I memoize this function?
  public foo() :any {
  }
}
```

I want to use a `class` to fit in with the idioms established in the existing TypeScript codebase.

Comment: What's the intent of changing it into a class? Just because you're using TS doesn't mean you have to convert everything to classes. Write the JS you would have written anyway, and add type annotations where you want.

Comment: Can you return arbitrary objects from typescript class constructors? I ask because this is not my codebase and I need to leverage the Angular injector. Everytime I try and do something in TS I run into an unanticipated roadblock.

Comment: What does TS have to do with this? Classes are an ES6 feature.

Comment: This is a typescript codebase. Presumably I have to therefore write in TS. Or at the very least if I don't then I have to dodge the type errors and I am unsure if I know how to do that.

Comment: TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript...

Comment: If the problem is that you're getting type errors you don't expect, why isn't your question about those errors? It sounds more like you have ES6 class questions and are blaming them on TypeScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways to do it:

```
// With Typescript syntax
class C {
  foo = memoize(() => {
  });
}

// Using ES6-style initialization instead of field initializers
class C {
    foo: () => any;
    constructor() {
        this.foo = memoize(() => {
        });
    }
}
```